# a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' o que significa este erro?

Tags: c, c++, compilação

Estou tentando compilar meu código, mas a compilação retorna o seguinte erro:

> a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token|

Sou iniciante e já olhei diversas vezes o código para entender o que pode estar acontecendo, mas não encontrei a origem do erro.

```
void menuAlunoCurso(){

        opcao = 0;
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\t\tSisCA - Menu do Matriculado *****");
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t *** Escolha uma opção ***");
        printf("\n\t\t\t 1------Cadastrar");
        printf("\n\t\t\t 2------Exibir");
        printf("\n\t\t\t 3------Pesquisar");
        printf("\n\t\t\t 4------Remover");
        printf("\n\t\t\t 7------Voltar ao menu anterior");
        printf("\n\n\t\t\tOpção: ");
        scanf("%d",&opcao);

    }
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor? Até ontem o código rodava perfeitamente.

Comment: Você só tem essa parte do código? Porque eu rodei ele aqui e funcionou. Na verdade fiz apenas uma modificação no qual coloquei o tipo da variável opcao. Ficando ` int opcao = 0;`

Comment: Provavelmente sua função está inserida num local não apropriado. Por favor, edite a pergunta para mostrar todo o código possível. @LeonardoCoelho Acho que essa variável está definida fora da função.

Comment: @felipeptcho pode ser que que sim, porque como eu disse, aqui funcionou da maneira que eu tentei.

Answer (score 2):

Normalmente esse erro se dá quando você esqueceu de fechar alguma chave na função anterior

Exemplo:

```
void outraFuncao(){
    //
    // Codigo da função...
    //
// Falta o } para essa função

void menuAlunoCurso(){

    opcao = 0;
    system("cls");
    printf("\t\t\tSisCA - Menu do Matriculado *****");
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t *** Escolha uma opção ***");
    printf("\n\t\t\t 1------Cadastrar");
    printf("\n\t\t\t 2------Exibir");
    printf("\n\t\t\t 3------Pesquisar");
    printf("\n\t\t\t 4------Remover");
    printf("\n\t\t\t 7------Voltar ao menu anterior");
    printf("\n\n\t\t\tOpção: ");
    scanf("%d",&opcao);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você colocou a definição da funcão "menuAlunoCurso" antes da chave final "}" da função anterior.

Algo assim:

```
void func()
{
    // bla
    // bla
    // bla

void menuAlunoCurso(){
   // bla
   // bla
   // bla
} // chave final de menuAlunoCurso 

} // chave final de func
```